# Showing all the posts in one page?

Tags: categories, tags

There are over 200 posts tagged with the keyword "Apple."

Each tag page -- example.com/tag/apple/page/2/ -- shows 10 posts.

So there are 20 tag pages.

Is it possible to show all these 200 post (links) in one page? I don't want to show any of the excerpt -- just consolidate all those 200 links in one page.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: do you want `example.com/tag/apple/` to show all posts, or a separate page?

Comment: When someone visits the tag page -- example.com/tag/apple -- he/she should be shown all the posts. No pages. Thanks, Milo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would consider the correct solution, and is the solution alluded to by Milo's comment (if I am not mistaken).

```
function alter_ppp_for_tags_wpse_88337($qry) {
  if ( is_tag() && $qry->is_main_query() ) {
    $qry->set('posts_per_page','-1');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_ppp_for_tags_wpse_88337');
```

Using `query_posts` will cause two requests to the database-- the main query, and the query triggered by the use of `query_posts`. By using a filter on `pre_get_posts` you alter the main query before posts are fetched and thus only hit the database once.

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: And if you want to target the "apple" tag specifically: `if (is_tag( 'apple' ) )`. Also, **be sure to include `&& $query->is_main_query()` in the conditional**.

Comment: S_ha_dum, you rock! That code works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Also, Chip Bennett, appreciate your response. Boy, you guys are genius. :)

Answer (score -1):

Its possible. You need to modify parameters in `query_posts()`. Use:

```
query_posts('tag'=>'apple', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)
```

`'nopaging'=>1` can also be used for listing all items. Check [Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) for detail.

Comment: **Do not use `query_posts`, ever**. Modify the main query via [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), create additional queries via [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Now I am more confused -- should I follow Nilambar's advice or go through Milo's links. Also, not sure where to add these codes! Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should go through Milo's links. `query_posts` is pretty much always a bad idea. Just don't use it.

Comment: Do not use `query_posts()`, ever, for *anything*. There is *always* a better, more appropriate way to modify or create a query.