# Changing H1 to Normal Links

Tags: tags

After following this tutorial -- [Showing all the posts in one page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88337/showing-all-the-posts-in-one-page) -- I was able to show all post links in one tag page.

Example: http://blogote.com/tag/facebook/

Now I have several H1/H2 headers in those tag pages -- more than 100s.

How can I convert these H1 titles into normal titles?

Here's the code:

```
$title = the_title( '<h1 class="' . esc_attr( $post->post_type ) . '-title entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>', false );
```

I have changed H1 to Strong tag, but is it possible to remove/refine the code further? I tried removing rel=bookmark and other elements but my efforts were unsuccessful (errors were shown after uploading the file).

I also want the fonts to be normal, small in size.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change this:

```
class="' . esc_attr( $post->post_type ) . '-title entry-title"
```

and make a special class for this usage. For example, make it:

```
class="fb-list"
```

and then style it however you like in your style.css file:

```
.fb-list { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; }
```

I'd also change the `<strong>` tag to a `<p>` or `<span>` or something that's more appropriate.

Comment: Hi jfacemyer, that worked! Why didn't I think of this before? You rock! Thanks...