# Bringing Ajax Loading Feature on Category Pages

Tags: categories, ajax

Following this post -- [Showing all the posts in one page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88337/showing-all-the-posts-in-one-page) -- I was able to create a tag and category page with all posts.

Example: http://blogote.com/apple/

The link contains over 200+ posts. Is there a way to show only 30-50 posts at a time and add a Twitter-like or Facebook-like "Load More" option? Probably we already have a plugin for this? Appreciate your response.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plugins like [Ajax pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-pagination/) or more configurable 
[WP Twitter/Facebook Style Pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-twitterfacebook-style-pagination/). Install it and use in your own theme.

Comment: Hi, there are no pages to the category page. Not sure where to add the codes given in the plugin. Will they really solve my problem? Till now, they haven't.